# Children's book about a boy being pushed off a cliff by a girl and breaking his leg, repercussions commence

Tags: identification-request

I was introduced to this work in my childhood in the early 90s through my grandparents personal library in their home (if it at all matters, at that time, Sandy, Utah); I do not recall the publish date, or any purely physical characteristics of the book itself.

If my recollection is accurate it was in a Hans Christian Andersen type of feel, or perhaps something like The Secret Garden. It was in English, probably not translated.

I am almost 100% sure this was a book, although if my memory is faulty due to being very young it could have been some kind of TV-movie, definitely very much a children's-novel-like story plot.

The setting is most likely in the western Alps. A girl, out of childish cruelty, goes too far with bullying and pushes a weak boy harder than she meant to, tumbling him off a cliff and crippling him. Upon realizing what she did runs away without helping. (I know the "girl causes boy to fall off cliff" part is **very vaguely** similar to what happens with Jill and Eustace in the beginning of The Silver Chair, but I am definitely thinking of a different book.) She later feels remorse and guilt for her actions. (And there is at some point later a scene with skiing?) The tables are turned at one point when the girl is in physical danger and the boy decides to help her instead of carrying the grudge, and possibly was in a unique position to help her *because* of his disability. They ultimately reconcile.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please read the [tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for identification requests and [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/26210/edit) to add as much pertinent information of the kind mentioned there, such as how long ago and where you read the book, what the book looked like, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Some details match "Treasures of the Snow": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasures_of_the_Snow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be [Treasures of the Snow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/543495.Treasures_of_the_Snow) by Patricia St. John, as mentioned in a comment by Ayshe? It was first published in 1950. There was also [a film adaptation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129454), which IMDB says had a TV release in the United States in 1983. My copy of the book contains several black-and-white photo plates of stills from the movie. So it's possible you remember both the book and the movie, or at least images from it.

The book is a children's story set in Switzerland. Most of the details you mentioned line up, *if* one splits the boy and the girl into three characters: Annette, her little brother Dani, and an older boy, Lucien.

> A girl, out of childish cruelty, goes too far with bullying and pushes a weak boy harder than she meant to, tumbling him off a cliff and crippling him.

Lucien, while picking on Dani, accidentally drops Dani's kitten into a rocky ravine with a river at the bottom. Dani tries to retrieve the kitten, slips, and falls.

(Annette tells Lucien's sister a version of events that assumes the worst about him: "Lucien threw Dani's kitten over the ravine, and Dani tried to rescue her. Lucien did not try to stop Dani at all. I shouldn't wonder if he pushed him." But the narrator makes clear that Lucien never intended to hurt the kitten or Dani.)

Dani lands on a boulder and breaks his leg. It heals poorly, so he has to use crutches thereafter.

> Upon realizing what she did runs away without helping.

Lucien assumes in a panic that Dani must have fallen into the river and drowned. Instead of going for help, he runs home and hides in the barn.

> She later feels remorse and guilt for her actions.

Lucien is horrified at the thought that he might have killed Dani. Once Dani is found alive, Lucien tries to make restitution by carving wooden toy animals for him, but Annette refuses to forgive him and throws the animals away.

> The tables are turned at one point when the girl is in physical danger and the boy decides to help her instead of carrying the grudge

Annette is out walking alone on a winter evening and sprains her ankle badly. Lucien happens to be skiing past and finds her. He is quite eager to help her, still hoping to make amends for what he did to Dani. Annette accepts his help and decides to finally forgive him.

> And there is at some point later a scene with skiing?

Toward the end of the book, Lucien hears about a surgeon who might be able to fix Dani's leg. Risking his life, he skis across a mountain pass in a blizzard to ask for the surgeon's help.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this had been bugging me for a while. My memory had indeed been fuzzy. I am grateful for the answer!